# Can we integrate with Cloud Service and internal AD environment

Tags: azure

I would like to ask one question as title. In some requirements we want to use internal AD account to run an application pool which was hosted in cloud service. And we found the instance of the cloud service does not in internal AD environment. Seems we should do some integration configuration before, but I don’t have any idea about it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff, you would need to do the following:

1) Setup a Virtual Network in Azure.

Virtual Network: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156007.aspx

2) Setup a VPN from your on-premise network to the Azure Virtual Network (VNET).  You can use either a Point-to-Site (basically server-to-network) or Site-to-Site (network-to-network) VPN.

Site-to-Site: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/

Point-to-Site: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/

3) Create at least one Virtual Machine and configure it as a Domain Controller that is joined to your on-premise Domain.  This DC will no different to any other DC you'd setup on-premise.

Stand-alone DC in Azure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn275963.aspx

4) Domain-join your Virtual Machines or Paas Web / Worker roles.  Web / Worker Roles are slightly tricky but it can be done.

A bit old, but gives you an idea: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_azure_connect_team_blog/archive/2010/12/10/domain-joining-windows-azure-roles.aspx

Then the last thing is to setup App Pool user's as you would normally.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate your on-premise Active Directory with your Azure Active Directory.

See: [Azure Active Directory](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-whatis/)

Comment: Brendan, thank you for reply. can you give me more detail information about how to integrate cloud service VM with on-premise AD.

Comment: if we has integrated with both of Azure AD and Local AD, then we can use Local AD account to login Azure VM?